# real vs complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

Can someone write REAL numbers in rectangular form as well? And if so, is it useful?

For example: On the complex plane, $(x + yi)$ is $x$ units on the Real $x$ axis and y units on the Imaginary y axis. If I say, $(x + y)$ is that the same as $x$ units on the Real $x$ axis and y units on the Real $y$ axis?

Also, can I say $(x + y + yi)$? Is that $x$ units on the Real $x$ axis, $y$ units on the Real $y$ axis, and $y$ units on the Imaginary $y$ axis?

Comment: If you're only thinking about the complex numbers as pairs of real numbers (i.e. without looking at the algebraic structure), then certainly you can talk about triple of real numbers; these triples will not be represented as a complex number though.  The use of $+$ here is not being used in lieu as a comma or anything of the sort.  It is an algebraic operation, and sending two real number $x$ and $y$ to another real number $z$ that just happens to be denoted by $x+y$.  Use something like $(x,y)$.

Comment: I'm confused, I thought rectangular form means + is being us as a comma? Like there are 6 dimensions (axes), an imaginary one that is paired with each real one?

Comment: For complex numbers, $x+yi$ is representing a *complex number*.  However, we can *model* the complex numbers as the set of all pairs of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}^2$, where the bijection between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by sending $x+yi$ to $(x,y)$.  However, in principle they are not the same.  With this in mind, we can view the $+$ in $x+yi$ as a sort of formal sum (analogous to a comma, in a way), but when you say something like $(x+yi)+(x'+y'i)$, this isn't the case, because the middle $+$ is actually meaningful: it is the addition of complex numbers....

Comment: ...and is an actual operation that outputs a new complex number $(x+x')+(y+y')i$.  Here $+$ means a couple different things again!  In $x+x'$ and $y+y'$ the $+$ is referring to the addition of real numbers, whereas the middle $+$ is more of the formal variety as in $x+yi$.  So when you say $x+y+yi$, you're really meaning the complex number with real part $x+y$ and imaginary part $y$.

Comment: Hayden I think I almost understand. I think the repetitive use of y is confusing me. So, lets take the complex number A + Bi. We can graph it on the complex plane with A units on the "x" axis and B units on the "y" axis. Now, can I graph A + Bi on the real plane as well? So if I take the point (1,1) it would be (1,1) on the real plane. What if I take (A + Bi,1)? Will that be (A + Bi) units on the x axis and 1 unit on the y axis?

Comment: The real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ of pairs of real numbers is exactly that: the set of pairs of **real** numbers.  So $(A+Bi,1)$ doesn't make sense when considered as an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (though it is certainly an element of $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}$, the set of pairs of a complex number and a real number).  You can put $A+Bi$ on the real plane via assigning it to $(A,B)$.  It is important to note that $\mathbb{C}$ is *much more* than simply $\mathbb{R}^2$; it has an algebraic structure on it, and while it can certainly be envisioned and realized as $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: ... it is a lot more than that.  I think noting this difference is important, as once you do that trying to do something like $(A+Bi,1)$ will more clearly not make sense in the context of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Great, I think I understand now! So, then I can represent (A + Bi, 1) on the C × R x R planes right? Which is 3 dimensional?

Comment: Well, that has two entries, a complex one $A+Bi$, and a real one $1$, so it would in $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}$.  In general, $A_1\times A_2\times \cdots \times A_n$ is the set of ordered $n$-tuples $(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n)$ where $a_i\in A_i$.  So $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ is the set of triples of real numbers.  I suppose you could imagine the $1$ in $(A+Bi,1)$ as a complex number, in which case you could say it is an element of $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}^2$, but it likely depends on the context.  Imagining $\mathbb{C}$ as two-dimensional (relative...

Comment: ... to $\mathbb{R}$), then $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}$ is three dimensional, yes.

Comment: To try not to get caught up over the meaning of what it means to be an element of $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}$ or something like that, I'd recommend just trying to approach it from a purely definitional point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Any function $f:{\rm I\!R}^2 \rightarrow {\rm I\!R}$ that is at least injective could be said to provide a way to "write REAL numbers in rectangular form". Usefulness would depend on what purpose this function fulfills. The example you gave:

$$
f(x,y) = x+y
$$

Is surjective, but not injective. So given (x+y) you cannot uniquely determine $x$ and $y$.

The second example you give is a function $f:{\rm I\!R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, which is both surjective and injective, hence bijective. Also it it additive so:
$$
f(x,y)=(x+y)+yi
$$
$$
f(w,t)=(w+t)+ti
$$
Hence:
$$
f(x,y)+f(w,t)=(x+y)+yi+(w+t)+ti = f(x+w,y+t)
$$

Therefore it maps x units on the Real x axis, y units on the Real y axis, and y units on the Imaginary y axis. If my understanding of this phrase is accurate.